# Is there a way to make a RunTimeClass default for a namespace?

Tags: kubernetes

I want to run pods with `runsc` as default on my k8s nodes but `kube-proxy` or other nodes can't be run via `runsc`. So, I want to automate the process in a way that after the Kubernetes start, every new pod will be run via `runsc`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/runtime-class/), this can be done with the below steps:

- [Configure the CRI implementation on nodes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/runtime-class/#1-configure-the-cri-implementation-on-nodes)
- [Create the corresponding RuntimeClass resources](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/runtime-class/#2-create-the-corresponding-runtimeclass-resources)
- Specify a `runtimeClassName` in the Pod spec.

A step by step guide alongside all necessary details can be found in the linked docs.

Notice that:

- low-level resources, such as `nodes` and `persistentVolumes`, are not in any namespace, `RuntimeClass` is a non-namespaced resource
- `RuntimeClass` assumes a homogeneous node configuration across the cluster by default (which means that all nodes are configured the same way with respect to container runtimes). To support heterogeneous node configurations, see [Scheduling](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/runtime-class/#scheduling) below.

Comment: I think I failed to present my question. kube-proxy, kube-apiserver can't run with runsc. so, after I spin up everything with runc. I tried to make runsc default for every pods I will start after. Making runsc on CRI implementation is problematic because if system pods like, kube-apiserver take a restart it will restart with runsc, and will fail.

Comment: I am afraid that it would not be doable with k8s help solely.